# Create a shareable URL from an AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have web app that shows venues on a map via markers and bootstrap cards.

I am trying to allow users to share specific venues and lists of venues with others but am having trouble with the implementation. This is because the data is taken from AJAX calls and there are no unique URLs generated that can be shared and, when clicked, show a user the specific data (eg. a venue or a list). Hence on localhost the URL always remains: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Here is an example of the Venue card that is created, alongside a Google Maps Marker, via AJAX data and a template literal when an address is searched. However, the Venue cannot currently be shared because there is no unique URL. I'd be grateful for guidance.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/electra/info_box/',
    data: {
      'venuename': venueName
    },
    success: function(data) {
      let venueId = data[0][0]
      let venueName = data[0][1]
      let venueAddress = data[0][2]
      let venueDescription = data[0][3]
      let source = data[0][4]
      let category = data[0][5]

      let myCol = $('<div id="col"></div>');
      let venueCard = $(
        `
      <div id="${venueName}-venue-card" class="card venue-card" data-idtext="${venueName}">
      <div class="card-body" id="${venueName}-cardbody" data-idtext="${venueName}">
      <div class="card-top" id="${venueName}-card-top" data-idtext="${venueName}">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="${venueName}-card" data-idtext="${venueName}">${venueName}</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle venue-address mb-2 text-muted">${venueAddress}</h6>
        <h6 class="venue-source card-subtitle">Added by ${source}</h6>
        <span class="card-info">
          <i id="${venueName}-bookmark" class="card-icon bi bi-bookmark-plus-fill default-bookmark" data-idtext="${venueId}"></i>
          <i id="${venueName}-share" class="card-icon bi bi-share-fill default-bookmark default-bookmark" data-idtext="${venueId}"></i> 
       </div>
       <div>
          <p class="card-text">${venueDescription}</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      `
      );
      venueCard.appendTo(myCol);
      myCol.appendTo('#venueCard');
```

Comment: `stringify` your marker array and upload it to your server. Get the server to generate a new model based on that data, along with a UUID/URL, then persist that data to either a DB or a JSON file local to the server.

Comment: Hmm okay this sounds like it's out of my hitting zone in terms of know how.

Comment: You're going to need a server to share the data so perhaps start there, and get [used to uploading data to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). If you're working with JS [Express/NodeJS](https://expressjs.com/) is a good place to start.